# How to remove a substring from string in SH not bash

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to modify input parameters of an SH script (it begins with #!/bin/sh). I found some solutions but they don't work here and need `bash`. They give me `bad substitution` error. so I look for a solution that works in SH (or whatever it is called)

The `bash_params` could be like "_learn _vil=bar _meet=foo". Here "_learn" acts as a flag. I want to set some variabels based on this flag and then remove it so that I can set other variables with `eval`.

Also, if you know better approaches please let me know

```
case $bash_params in
  *"_learn"*) # learn is enabled
      _learn_sp=True
      tt="_learn"
      bash_params="${bash_params%"$tt"}" # it doesn't work
      bash_params="${bash_params/_learn//}" # this gives Bad substitution error

      _lsp=False
    ;;

eval ${bash_params}
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @konsolebox I use Ubuntu 20.4 default terminal. I also can't change it to `bash` because it gives me some other errors.

Comment: Note that using `eval` here is a bad idea: bash gives you tools like `printf %q` and `${var@Q}` that can be used to generate eval-safe strings with untrusted data, whereas `sh` _doesn't have the tools necessary to make `eval` safe_ unless the strings you're passing it contain only text that your script contains strict control over (no filenames, no user-provided arguments, etc).

Comment: And even when using `eval` _is_ appropriate, `eval "$params"` is safer than `eval $params`; the latter subjects you to word-splitting, globbing, and then pasting of the results back into a single string _before_ the parsing process starts, so it's an easy way for an unexpected glob character in your arguments to cause filenames (and any code they may contain) to be injected into the code that's then run through the parser.

Comment: @Ahmad `${bash_params%_learn}` and `${bash_params%_learn*}`should work. You should elaborate your actual goal.

Comment: @konsolebox as I wrote they give me errors like "Bad substituation" (the second one). I thgouth it's because the script begins with #!bin/sh

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for guides. It mostly used for simple params, so I guess using string quotation it can be safe

Comment: `%` only removes *suffixes*, not arbitrary substrings.

Comment: @Ahmad If you're using dash they shouldn't give "bad substitution". Have you tried it now, exactly as they are?

Comment: @konsolebox Dash, sh, bash what a mess! anyways, yes I used it exactly and it gives the error. My Vim editor even highlight it as red!!! (the /_learn//`) part

Comment: I didn't mention `/_learn//`. That surely will give you substitution error. I said `${bash_params%_learn}` and `${bash_params%_learn*}`.

Comment: @konsolebox sorry, no they don't work!!! I forgot to remove the solution with sed and thought its working! .... just `${bash_params%_learn*}` works but it removes the rest of parameters too

Comment: @Ahmad Ok so that's what you meant by "not working". Sed it is then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe to `sed`.

```
bash_params=$(echo "$bash_params" | sed "s/$tt//")
```